# Looking for clarification about certain syntax in TeamCity agent requirements

Tags: .net, teamcity

I have a Windows build agent, and a configuration that builds a Windows service, using the Visual Studio Tests runner (in this case, using VS 2015).

If I enable that step, I get an implicit agent requirement of `Exists=>DotNetFramework4\.5.*_x64 exists`.  That parameter doesn't exist on the agent (it's not in the agent's list of reported Configuration Parameters).  Separately, there is an implicit parameter (presumably from some other build step) that requires `DotNetFramework4.0_x86 exists`.  That param *does* exist on the build agent.

If I disable the test build step, the `Exists=>DotNetFramework4\.5.*_x64 exists` implicit requirement is still listed in the box on the Agent Requirements tab of the build configuration, but the Agent is now marked as compatible.

My first question here is, what is the Exists=> notation implying? `DotNetFramework4\.5.*_x64` absolutely does not exist as a param on the build agent, but I'd expect that implicit requirement to disappear when I disable the step, or at least somehow be marked as a requirement for a disabled step.

Comment: Can you please list out the build steps you are using? Which step are you referring to when you say "disable the test build step"? The Exists=> has the ability to check if an agent's system properties (with the prefix of sys.), environment variables (with the prefix of env.), or configuration parameter (with no prefix) exists.

Comment: I see now. You're referring to the Visual Studio Tests Build step. 
I was not able to replicate this on my Teamcity instance. I am using versoin 2020.1.